# redirect if session doen't exist

Tags: php, session, redirect

i m trying to redirect to attempt page if user fills incorrect information...
on the other hand if attempt page got refreshed want it to be redirected on login page...
i m using session for that...

```
if (isset($c))
{
    $q = mysql_query("select * from registeration where email='$a' and password='$b'");
    $r = mysql_num_rows($q);

    if($r)
    {
        $_SESSION["Authenticated"] = 1;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $a;
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["Authenticated"] = 0;
        $_SESSION["att"] = 1;
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION["att"]))
    {
        header("location:attempt1.php");
    }
    else
    {
        session_write_close();
        header('location:profile.php');
    }
}
```

the above mentioned code is redirecting on attempt1.php
but code on attempt1.php redirecting back to index.php

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["att"]))
{
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=index.php\">";
}
```

i want attempt1.php code to redirect on user on index.php if session is not set..
and destroy session on refresh or direct page load...
so that direct access to this page results in redirection to index page
please help friends..

**ANSWER**  ***ANSWER***  ***ANSWER***
all the questions i asked i made silly mistakes...
here in this question i had not started session wile storing session variables....
add the below code in first line of login script

```
session_start();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
//try this code  
<?php 
session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION["att"]))
   {
      header("location: index.php");
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your asking to redirect if a session doesn't exist, since a session requires an ID you should be able to check against that:

```
if(!(session_id()) header("Location: /mypage.php");
```

Comment: Session ID is created automatically, it's the ID that ties your user to what is stored on the server. Whether in a cookie or by the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if(empty($_SESSION))
{
  header("Location: /mypage.php");
}
else
{
    // do something ....
}
```

-
Thanks